# Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

"Visual Studio Community 2015"
How long Visual Studio Community 2015 will be free, forever or specified time period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be free indefinitely, like VS 2013 Community.  Before that, they offered free Express Editions.  I think it's safe to say that as long as Visual Studio is a thing, there will be a free version.